# Not render when Apollo query is 'loading' - React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, apollo

I have a react-redux app that uses Apollo client to make queries to my api GraphQL.

I have a **GridContainer** that makes the query call using `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(GridContainerWithData);` where **GridContainerWithData** is a *const* that makes the query with graphql(gql`...)

This returns **data** in my props containing: the query response, if there is an error and the loading state (true or false).

Right now, I'm managing the loading myself using `if(loading) {}`.

The problem in this is my component renders when it's in loading state and then again when the query is done loading. If I don't use the `if(loading) {}`, I get an error saying I need to return something when the query is in loading state.

Is there any way to tell the component to not render when the query is *loading*?

I tried using

```
shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps) {
    if (this.props.data.loading !== nextProps.data.loading) {
      console.log(‘i will rerender’, nextProps.data.loading);
      return true;
    }else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

but no luck there.

Is there any way to tell the component to not render when the query is *loading*?

EDIT:

This is my GridContainer if it can help anyone.

```
class ActionsToDoGridContainer extends Component {

 render () {
   const {error} = this.props.data;

   if (error) {
     return (
       <div className='ComponentDistance'>
         An unexpected error happened :
         {error}
       </div>);
    } else {
     return (
        <div className='ComponentDistance'>
          <ActionsToDoGrid {...this.props}/>
         ActionsToDoButtons {...this.props}/>
        </div>
     );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit: The poster of the question resolved his own issue with this code:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) { 
  if (nextProps.data.loading === false) { 
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I think you were thinking in the right direction with `shouldComponentUpdate`, but instead of checking to see if the loading state is different, check to see if your data is different.

```
shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps) {
    const thisData = this.props.data.queryDataResponse;
    const nextData = nextProps.data.queryDataResponse;
    if (!someLibrary.deepEquals(thisData, nextData)) {
      return true;
    }else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

If the data changes, your function will return true and update.  You may run in to some edge cases so don't forget about this function when things seem to break

Comment: Unfortunately, when I return null, my grid disappears for the loading time until I receive the new data. I would like to keep my grid with my previous data until the query has finished loading.

Comment: i updated my answer.  I think you can use shouldcomponentupdate for this

Comment: Ok now it renders 2 times at start of the application (I think that's normal).
The **first action** I do (changing page) only renders once (when it is finished loading). But at the **second time** I change page (or third or fourth or...), it renders 2 times (loading and not loading).

Any idea why?

Comment: that makes sense... your reducer is returning a new state object each time the `loading` flag changes.  You need to do a deepEqual comparison by value. you can use lodash or some similar library that has deepEqual or write it yourself.  Editing my comment

Comment: Actually, I found a way to make it work with `shouldComponentUpdate()`.
I implemented this in my **Container** juste before the _render()_ function:

```shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps) {
if (nextProps.data.loading === false) {
return true;
}else {
return false;
}
}```

Comment: Actually simplified my code in shouldComponentUpdate. No need for **if** or **else** statement, you only need this line: `return nextProps.data.loading === false;`